# How can I search a specific list of files with ripgrep?

Tags: ripgrep

I've got a list of files that I would like to search for a pattern with ripgrep.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

ripgrep accepts file paths as arguments. So just pass your files as arguments:

```
rg pattern file1 file2 ...
```

If your list is in a file, with one path per line, then use xargs:

```
xargs -d '\n' -a list-file rg pattern
```

Or if it's a list generated from `find`, then:

```
find ./ ... -print0 | xargs -0 rg pattern
```

Comment: Searching only some specific file can be done like `find . -iname '*finde_me*.md' -print0 | xargs -0 rg 'search term'`

Comment: In that case, you might as well just use `rg 'search term' -g '*finde_me*.md'` :-)

Comment: Nice! Started using ripgrep a couple of weeks ago and it's truly amazing! Learning so much!

Comment: Is there a performance benefit in not using xargs, find, etc?

Comment: There might be, given that, e.g., `find` is single threaded and ripgrep is multi-threaded. Why not try both and compare them for your use case?